# Guitar notes on the Staff

Tags: guitar

I like to know learn about Music Theory (for any instruments)and How to know notes on the Guitar are put on the sttaf ? for everystrings and every frets? can you help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. If you know the name of the note then you'll know where on the staff it goes. Are you aware of note names and how they fit on the strings of the guitar?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

[notes on the staff](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-do-the-notes-on-the-staff-relate-to-the-guitar.html)

Also note: for guitar music, it's normally written to be played an octave higher than standard notation, so that most of the guitar's range can be made to fit on just a treble staff (so no bass staff is needed).  You'll often see a little "8 va" written on the music, but a lot of people leave that out.